# using underscore variables with Backbone Boilerplate fetchTemplate function

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am building an application using the [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate), and am having some trouble getting underscore template variables to work. I have a resource named Goal. My Goal View's render function looks like this:

```
render: function(done) {
  var view = this;

  namespace.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {
    view.el.innerHTML = tmpl();
    done(view.el);
  });
}
```

I'm calling it inside of another view, like so:

```
var Goal = namespace.module("goal"); 

App.View = Backbone.View.extend({

  addGoal: function(done) {

    var view = new Goal.Views.GoalList({model: Goal.Model});

    view.render(function(el) {
      $('#goal-list').append(el);
    });
  }
});
```

I'm using local storage to save my data, and it's being added just fine. I can see it in the browser, but for some reason, when I load up the app, and try to fetch existing data, i get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: title
```

Where title is the only key I'm storing. It is a direct result of calling:

```
tmpl();
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There must be a variable `title` somewhere in your code. Is there no line number associated with the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is looking for a variable `title`, probably like this `<%- title %>`. You need to pass it an object like this `tmpl({ title: 'Some title' })`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I wasn't passing in the model when i created the view, which was making it impossible to get the models data. Once I passed in the model correctly, I could then pass the data to tmpl, as correctly stated by @abraham.

```
render: function(done) {
    var 
    view = this,
    data = this.model.toJSON(); 

    clam.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {

    view.el.innerHTML = tmpl(data);

    done(view.el);
    });
},
```